# Should the 'netflix' tag be renamed to 'netflixapi'?

Tags: discussion, retag-request

From the [Netflix API documentation](http://developer.netflix.com/docs):

> If you are unable to find an answer to your question or concern in
> these documentation pages, you can consult with other Netflix API
> developers at [stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/netflixapi) by using the tag “netflixapi”.

As of today, there are only 86 questions with the [Netflix tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/netflix) and the fact that they closed the registration to have access to the API may not help seeing new questions on the subject, but I still think it would be worth it.

Comment: Does it *really* need renamed? It's not really *our* responsibility if Netflix jumps the gun and creates some imaginary tag in their documentation that doesn't really exist. I don't see the fact that they're telling people to use that tag as a valid reason to rename it. They should just fix their page.

Comment: @animuson I do agree with you and I have hesitated before posting this question. But seeing that the link on their website goes with this tag...and netflixapi would make more sense, don't you think?

Comment: it would be `netflix-api` though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- It should be synonymized, so that users from Netflix will not have any trouble if they follow Netflix's documentation when using our site.
- I personally find `netflix` better.  I'm always more likely to type something short and simple.  It's more readable.  The only case for splitting them would be if there were a wide array of Netflix-like services, but this isn't the case.
- But seriously, are people going to be googling up "netflixapi," or "Netflix" "API"?

That leaves the underlying question of whether we should conform to Netflix's standards or they should conform to ours.  **The answer is they should conform to ours.**  It's good for our business and community when other folks do their Q&A over us, but only on the condition these questions are a good fit for Stack Overflow *in their own right.*  It is our responsibility to maintain a high-quality Q&A site, and if that means we deem `netflix` a better tag than `netflixapi` for whatever reason, then that's what happens.

Note that in deciding to partially host their support on our site, they are yielding to our judgment over matters related to their support questions.  This includes things like choosing proper tags.  We are in the business of delivering high quality Q&A for askers *and future visitors*, which is exactly what they are "hiring" us to do, which means they get the full package - right down to the meta discussions, making sure we tag their questions the best way possible to this end.  In theory (and I think in practice), they like this.  It's even *less* they have to perfect or worry about.

For the record, I think their action was probably germane.  Ideally they'd be clear we're our own show and aren't contracted to field Q&A (seriously, who just answers questions for fun?), but as long as we don't get a continuous flood of poor quality `netflixapi` questions this is welcome.  Chances are if they're too unclear or their API users are too unfamiliar with Stack Overflow they'll get angry complaints about how mean we are until they fix their language.

Comment: What you suggest at the end is that we leave it the way it is and see what happens?